# WordPress send JSON data to REST API using AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to send json data to a custom REST API endpoint that will simply return the data sent. I am not sure what I need to do to pass this data in. I am currently getting a blank object.

PHP Code:

```
define( 'BRIGHTBRID_PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );


//Localize/register/enqueue javascript file
add_action( 'init', 'bbwd_enqueu' );
function bbwd_enqueu() {
   wp_register_script( "bright-bridge-custom", BRIGHTBRID_PLUGIN_URL.'assets/brightbridgeweb.js', array('jquery'));
   wp_localize_script( 'bright-bridge-custom', 'bbwdAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));        

   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'bright-bridge-custom' );
}


//Add custom REST Endpoint
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function($data) {
  register_rest_route( 'bright-bridge-custom-code/v1', '/test', [
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'test',
  ] );
} );
function test($data){
    return $data;
}

//button to exicute ajax request to REST API 
add_shortcode( 'bp_testing', 'bp_test' );
function bp_test(){
    return "<button onclick='testClick()'>Test Me</h2>";
}
```

Javascript Code:

```
function testClick(){
    let data = ["test", "Test2"]
    
    jQuery.ajax({
            url: window.location.origin+'/wp-json/bright-bridge-custom-code/v1/test', 
            type: "POST",
            data : data,
            success:function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                    },
            timeout: 0,
            error:function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a `$data` object in the test function, this object is of type `WP_REST_Request Object` and before being returned it is encoded in json format.

So, to get any object other than `{}` (blank), you could return the result of a database query or any other type of object.

For example by changing the function:

```
function test($data){
    return $data;
}
```

to this:

```
function test($data){
    return array("a" => 1, "b" => 2);
}
```